# Different redirects on form submit in a Django view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Is it possible to redirect to a page or another when sending a request.POST in a Django view, depending on which button has been used?

Example:

```
<form id="myForm" action='?'>
    <submit button1>
    <submit button2>
</form>
```

and then in my view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid() and button1:
        form.save()
        return redirect('page1')
    if form.is_valid() and button2:
        form.save()
        return redirect('page2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

**html**

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="button1">
    <input type="submit" name="button2">
</form>
```

**Views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid() and 'button1' in request.POST:
        form.save()
        return redirect('page1')
    if form.is_valid() and 'button2' in request.POST:
        form.save()
        return redirect('page2')
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I think we both got to a similar solution! I'll mark yours as the answer for taking the time, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it like so:

```
    <input class="button" value='update' type="submit" name="action" form="eventForm"/>
    <input class="button" value='submit' type="submit" name="action" form="eventForm"/>
```

And then in the view:

```
if request.POST['action'] == 'submit':
[...]
elif request.POST['action'] == 'update'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Give your submit buttons the same name but different values

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="button1">Button 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="button2">Button 2</button>
```

Which button was clicked will then be available in request.POST

```
if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    if request.POST['submit'] == 'button1':
        return redirect('page1')
    elif request.POST['submit'] == 'button2':
        return redirect('page2')
```

Comment: Yes we did, three answers all in parallel LOL